# javascript adding and subtracting using input type checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, calculator

I have code that works but was wondering if there is a way to condense it with JS loops?  I tried but I'm have trouble with it. I'm trying to build a calculator webpage for a game I plan on playing.  The "hide" is a material item for the skinning activity in the game.  I am anticipating that there will be several material items.  Thanks!

```js
total = 0;
hide1 = 1;
hide2 = 1;
hide3 = 1;

function addUp(num, x) {
  if (x == "hide1" && hide1 == 1) {
    temp = document.theForm.ttl.value;
    tempo = parseInt(temp);
    numo = parseInt(num);
    nwTemp = tempo + numo;
    document.theForm.ttl.value = nwTemp;
    hide1 = 0;
    return hide1;
  }
  if (x == "hide1" && hide1 == 0) {
    temp = document.theForm.ttl.value;
    tempo = parseInt(temp);
    numo = parseInt(num);
    nwTemp = tempo - numo;
    document.theForm.ttl.value = nwTemp;
    hide1 = 1;
  }
  if (x == "hide2" && hide2 == 1) {
    temp = document.theForm.ttl.value;
    tempo = parseInt(temp);
    numo = parseInt(num);
    nwTemp = tempo + numo;
    document.theForm.ttl.value = nwTemp;
    hide2 = 0;
    return hide2;
  }
  if (x == "hide2" && hide2 == 0) {
    temp = document.theForm.ttl.value;
    tempo = parseInt(temp);
    numo = parseInt(num);
    nwTemp = tempo - numo;
    document.theForm.ttl.value = nwTemp;
    hide2 = 1;
  }
  if (x == "hide3" && hide3 == 1) {
    temp = document.theForm.ttl.value;
    tempo = parseInt(temp);
    numo = parseInt(num);
    nwTemp = tempo + numo;
    document.theForm.ttl.value = nwTemp;
    hide3 = 0;
    return hide3;
  }
  if (x == "hide3" && hide3 == 0) {
    temp = document.theForm.ttl.value;
    tempo = parseInt(temp);
    numo = parseInt(num);
    nwTemp = tempo - numo;
    document.theForm.ttl.value = nwTemp;
    hide3 = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="theForm" style="display:block;border:1px">
  <div id="t1" style="display:none;">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="addUp(4, 'hide1')">
Beginner's Leather Hood
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" onClick="addUp(8, 'hide2')">
Beginner's Leather Armor
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" onClick="addUp(4, 'hide3')">
Beginner's Leather Shoes
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="t2" style="display:none;">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="addUp(8, 'hide4')">
Novice's Leather Hood
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" onClick="addUp(16, 'hide5')">
Novice's Leather Armor
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" onClick="addUp(8, 'hide6')">
Novice's Leather Shoes
    <br/>
  </div>
  Total Number:
  <input type="text" name="ttl" value=0>
</form>
```

Comment: you are not actually using x at anything though?

Comment: I don't understand how the hide1, hide2, hide3 variables are used to show/hide things, can you add an explanation of that?

Comment: Could you maybe also explain what you are trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for you?

```
total = 0;
var hide = [];
hide[1] = 1;
hide[2] = 1;
hide[3] = 1;

function addUp(num, x) {
    var index = parseInt(x.replace("hide",""));
    if(hide[index] == 1)
    {
        temp = document.theForm.ttl.value;
        tempo = parseInt(temp);
        numo = parseInt(num);
        nwTemp = tempo + numo;
        document.theForm.ttl.value = nwTemp;
        hide[index] = 0;
        return hide[index];
    }
    else if(hide[index] == 0)
    {
        temp = document.theForm.ttl.value;
        tempo = parseInt(temp);
        numo = parseInt(num);
        nwTemp = tempo - numo;
        document.theForm.ttl.value = nwTemp;
        hide[index] = 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Elentriel!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  You just saved me a whole lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider looking at [data-* attributes](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/10/using-data-attributes-in-javascript-and-css/) and [event listeners](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp).   You could have a data attribute for the value of each checkbox, and then an event listener for the change event of the checkbox.